# How to sort an array of Objects using string type object's key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array like this

```js
 let years =[
       {id: 3, name: "2016", age: "None"},
       {id: 1, name: "2017", age: "None"},
       {id: 2, name: "2015", age: "None"},
       {id: 5, name: "2018", age: "None"},
       {id: 3, name: "2018/2019", age: "None"}
       ]
       
years.sort((c1, c2) => {
        return c2.name - c1.name;
       });
       
console.log(years);
```

I couldn't deal with this "2018/2017" way how can I do it what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there...Just a little change in your sort callback and it's done::

```js
let years = [
    { id: 3, name: '2016', age: 'None' },
    { id: 1, name: '2017', age: 'None' },
    { id: 2, name: '2015', age: 'None' },
    { id: 5, name: '2018', age: 'None' },
    { id: 3, name: '2018/2019', age: 'None' },
];
years.sort((c1, c2) => {
    var n1 = c1.name;
    var n2 = c2.name;
    if(n1 > n2){return -1;
    }else if(n2 > n1){ return 1;
}else{return 0;}
   });
console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const years = [
    { id: 3, name: '2016', age: 'None' },
    { id: 1, name: '2017', age: 'None' },
    { id: 2, name: '2015', age: 'None' },
    { id: 5, name: '2018', age: 'None' },
    { id: 3, name: '2018/2019', age: 'None' },
];

years.sort((c1, c2) => c2.name.localeCompare(c1.name));

console.log(years);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
years.sort((c1, c2) => {
  if (c1.name > c2.name) return -1;
  if (c1.name < c2.name) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash `_.sortBy`

```
var years =
[{id: 5, name: "2018", age: "None"},
 {id: 3, name: "2018/2017", age: "None"},
 {id: 1, name: "2017", age: "None"},
 {id: 3, name: "2016", age: "None"},
 {id: 2, name: "2015", age: "None"}]

_.sortBy(years, ['name']);
```

Output would be

[image]